# ExtJS + IE10 script execution order issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, extjs

I have this snippet loading to iframe of a bigger app, having scripts declarations in the `<head>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js"></script>
    ...
```

But I'm getting `'Ext' is undefined` error thrown from within my-script.js.
Dev tool revealed that both started to load in parallel and my-script.js has finished loaded first as it is much smaller.

So here is a question: why is that IE uses asynchronous mode by default for ordinal scripts definition?
And how could I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `defer` on both script tags like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js" defer></script>
```

If this won't help, try loading `ext-all.js` first and use

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    // load my-script.js
});
```

to load your own script.

More of "defer": http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp